# Python | Voice Asistent, не понимает 2 слова одновременно

Tags: python, google-speech-recognition

смотрите код работает на одно слово, однако если их будет 2 то к сожалению он ничего не поймёт

```
from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer  # оффлайн-распознавание от Vosk
import speech_recognition  # распознавание пользовательской речи (Speech-To-Text)
import pyttsx3  # синтез речи (Text-To-Speech)
import wave  # создание и чтение аудиофайлов формата wav
import json  # работа с json-файлами и json-строками
import os  # работа с файловой системой
import random




class VoiceAssistant:
    """
    Настройки голосового ассистента, включающие имя, пол, язык речи
    """
    name = ""
    sex = ""
    speech_language = ""
    recognition_language = ""


def setup_assistant_voice():
    """
    Установка голоса по умолчанию (индекс может меняться в 
    зависимости от настроек операционной системы)
    """
    voices = ttsEngine.getProperty("voices")

    if assistant.speech_language == "en":
        assistant.recognition_language = "en-US"
        if assistant.sex == "man":
            # Microsoft Zira Desktop - English (United States)
            ttsEngine.setProperty("voice", voices[1].id)
        else:
            # Microsoft David Desktop - English (United States)
            ttsEngine.setProperty("voice", voices[2].id)
    else:
        assistant.recognition_language = "ru-RU"
        # Microsoft Irina Desktop - Russian
        ttsEngine.setProperty("voice", voices[0].id)


def play_voice_assistant_speech(text_to_speech):
    """
    Проигрывание речи ответов голосового ассистента (без сохранения аудио)
    :param text_to_speech: текст, который нужно преобразовать в речь
    """
    ttsEngine.say(str(text_to_speech))
    ttsEngine.runAndWait()


def record_and_recognize_audio(*args: tuple):
    """
    Запись и распознавание аудио
    """
    with microphone:
        recognized_data = ""

        # регулирование уровня окружающего шума
        recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(microphone, duration=2)

        try:
            print("Listening...")
            audio = recognizer.listen(microphone, 5, 5)

            with open("microphone-results.wav", "wb") as file:
                file.write(audio.get_wav_data())

        except speech_recognition.WaitTimeoutError:
            print("Can you check if your microphone is on, please?")
            return

        # использование online-распознавания через Google 
        # (высокое качество распознавания)
        try:
            print("Started recognition...")
            recognized_data = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language="ru").lower()

        except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError:
            pass

        # в случае проблем с доступом в Интернет происходит 
        # попытка использовать offline-распознавание через Vosk
        except speech_recognition.RequestError:
            print("Trying to use offline recognition...")
            recognized_data = use_offline_recognition()

        return recognized_data


def use_offline_recognition():
    """
    Переключение на оффлайн-распознавание речи
    :return: распознанная фраза
    """
    recognized_data = ""
    try:
        # проверка наличия модели на нужном языке в каталоге приложения
        if not os.path.exists("models/vosk-model-small-ru-0.4"):
            print("Please download the model from:\n"
                  "https://alphacephei.com/vosk/models and unpack as 'model' in the current folder.")
            exit(1)

        # анализ записанного в микрофон аудио (чтобы избежать повторов фразы)
        wave_audio_file = wave.open("microphone-results.wav", "rb")
        model = Model("models/vosk-model-small-ru-0.4")
        offline_recognizer = KaldiRecognizer(model, wave_audio_file.getframerate())

        data = wave_audio_file.readframes(wave_audio_file.getnframes())
        if len(data) > 0 and offline_recognizer.AcceptWaveform(data):
            recognized_data = offline_recognizer.Result()

            # получение данных распознанного текста из JSON-строки 
            # (чтобы можно было выдать по ней ответ)
            recognized_data = json.loads(recognized_data)
            recognized_data = recognized_data["text"]
    except Exception:
        print("Sorry, speech service is unavailable. Try again later")

    return recognized_data


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # инициализация инструментов распознавания и ввода речи
    recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
    microphone = speech_recognition.Microphone()

    # инициализация инструмента синтеза речи
    ttsEngine = pyttsx3.init()

    # настройка данных голосового помощника
    assistant = VoiceAssistant()
    assistant.name = "Siry"
    assistant.sex = "man"
    assistant.speech_language = "ru"

    # установка голоса по умолчанию
    setup_assistant_voice()
    while True:
        # старт записи речи с последующим выводом распознанной речи
        # и удалением записанного в микрофон аудио
        voice_input = record_and_recognize_audio()
        os.remove("microphone-results.wav")
        print(voice_input)

        # отделение комманд от дополнительной информации (аргументов)
        voice_input = voice_input.split(" ")
        command = voice_input[0]
        
        if "привет" in command:
            h = random.randint(1,2)
            if h == 2:
                play_voice_assistant_speech('Хай, чувак')
            elif h == 1:
                play_voice_assistant_speech('Привет глупый человек')
        
        elif "открой google" == command:
           play_voice_assistant_speech('Привет глупый человек')
```

Comment: Можно папробывать использовать find() будет понимать предложения

Comment: @СергейШ можете полностью обьяснить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я знаю как сделать ещё лучше! смотри код ниже

```
command = 'd'.join(voice_input)
```

так как voice_input это list ты можешь его конвертировать в строку. а 'd' это то через что будут связыватся слова из списке, рекомендую ставить пробел а не букву!

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

voice_input = 'открой google чувак'

voice_input = voice_input.split(" ")
command = voice_input[0]

if "привет" == command:
    h = random.choice(['Хай, чувак', 'Привет глупый человек'])
    print(h)

elif "открой" == command:
    if "google" == voice_input[1]:
        print('google')
```

мой вариант:

```
def google():
    print("google")
    
def hello():
    h = random.choice(['Хай, чувак', 'Привет глупый человек'])
    print(h)
    
voice_input = 'пожалуйста открой google, чувак'
# voice_input = "привет, чувак"
commands = {"открой google": google, 'привет': hello}
for command in commands:
    if voice_input.find(command) != -1:
        vv = commands[command]
        vv()
```

вывод

```
google
```

при

```
voice_input = "привет, чувак"
```

вывод

```
Хай, чувак
```

Comment: работает только привет(

Comment: когда прошу сказать открой гугл, то гугл не открывается, я txt заменил на command

Comment: @L1meek 'как пример' рабочий, значить вы что-то делаете не так.

Comment: Я тебе повышу репутацию, так как ответ полезен, но это не то

Comment: @СергейШ у вас ошибка заключается в том, что опять же, берётся только первое слово, а взять 2 слова из 1 невозможно

Comment: "у вас ошибка заключается в том" Это ваша ошибка :), первая часть ответа была дописана на оснований вашего кода. А вот вторая часть ответа лишена этого недостатка. Если voice_input = 'пожалуйста открой google, чувак' найдет словосочитание 'открой google' и выполнит команду связанную с этим словосочитание. Я на этом ресурсе не ради репутаций :)

Answer (score 0):

смотри, если ты даже списал, и ты хоть немного шаришь в python, то там всё просто

> смотри там где у тебя написано command = voice_input[0]

ты берёшь только первое слово записанное из voice_input, незнаю почему

> но отсчёт там начинается с 0

если так подумать ты можешь взять 4 слова, думаю тебе хватит,
тебе поможет следующий код

```
try:
    find = voice_find[0] + voice_find[1] + voice_find[2] + voice_find[3]
except:
    try:
        find = voice_find[0] + voice_find[1] + voice_find[2]
    except:
        try:
            find = f'{voice_find[0]}{voice_find[1]}'
        except:
            find = voice_input[0]
```

Comment: Это то что мне и нужно было, спасибо большое:3